# Unable to understand an application of Minkowski's inequality

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis

Consider the following exerpt from the paper "[Non-linear Quantum Processes](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/1970628.pdf?casa_token=XlxRoq02P7EAAAAA:njDNCfwom4wv_orM3R3pSBE_LoMzF7Ofh2XzK7DxIGwLD8vjq54hHbxNj4KsONV1txJIvFYTH8FwyeHPUB__56i5bnm2CjwXs_f1rRu7hKZTv8-Sr2zz)" by Segal:

> with the norm $\|F\|=\left(\int\|F(x)\|^p \, d x\right)^{1 / p}$, then the operator $T_1^{\prime}: F \rightarrow G$, where $G(x)=\int K_1(x, y) F(y) \, d y$, exists and is a contraction from $L_p\left(M_1, \mathbf{B}\right)$ to $L_q\left(M_1, \mathbf{B}\right)$. For the mapping $y \rightarrow K_1(x, y) F(y)$ is easily seen to be strongly measurable from $M_1$ to $\mathbf{B}$, for each $x$; and
> $$
> \|G(x)\| \leqq \int K_1(x, y)\|F(y)\| \, d y,
> $$
> i.e., $\|G(\cdot)\|=T_1(\|F(\cdot)\|)$, so that ||$G(\cdot)\left\|_{\mathbf{B}}\right\|_q \leqq\|\| F(\cdot)\left\|_{\mathbf{B}}\right\|_p$.

I'm unable to understand the equation $\|G(x)\| \leqq \int K_1(x, y)\|F(y)\|\, d y$. What does the norm in $\|F(y)\|$ mean? Are we just taking the absolute value $|F(y)|$? I remember being told that this inequality concerns Minkowski's inequality, but I'm unable to see this from the notation. Minkowski's inequality should have implied $$\|G(x)\|_p\leq \int \|K_1(x,y)F(y)\|_p\, dy$$
Any help with this would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand\B{\mathbf B}$The function $F$ takes values in a separable Banach space $\B$, and $\|F(y)\|$ is the $\B$-norm of $F(y)$. We have
$$G(x)=\int K_1(x,y)F(y)dy,$$
where $K_1$ is positive. So, for any $b^*$ in the dual space $\B^*$ with $\|b^*\|\le1$, we have
$$b^*(G(x))=\int K_1(x,y)b^*(F(y))dy\le\int K_1(x,y)\|F(y)\|dy.$$
Thus,
$$\|G(x)\|\le\int K_1(x,y)\|F(y)\|dy. \quad\Box$$

Comment: Thank you. I'd also like to draw your attention to the following related question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461660/on-a-deceptively-tricky-calculus-problem?noredirect=1#comment1197565_461660

Comment: @matilda : I saw it, but don't have good ideas about that at this point.

Comment: No problem, thank you.