# If the operators $B_i'$ satisfy an inequality, prove that $B_1'+\dotsb+ B_n'$ also satisfies the same inequality

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, stochastic-processes, random-walks

Related: [On a deceptively tricky calculus problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461660/on-a-deceptively-tricky-calculus-problem).

The way that Leonard Gross proves the log Sobolev inequality is in the following stages:

1. He proves that for any operator $B$ that satisfies the log Sobolev inequality $\int f^2 \log \frac{f}{\lVert f\rVert_2}d\mu\leq \langle Bf,f\rangle$, the operator $e^{-tB}$ is hypercontractive.
2. He then proves the log Sobolev inequality for carefully chosen operators $B_i$ on the discrete probability space $\{-1,1\}$ with $\{1/2,1/2\}$ as the corresponding probabilities.
3. He then uses Segal's lemma [Lemma 1.4 from [Segal - Construction of Non-Linear Local Quantum Processes: I]](https://doi.org/10.2307/1970628) to show that if $e^{-tB_i}$ are hypercontractive, then $e^{-t(B_1+\dots B_n)}$ is also hypercontractive, and hence $(B_1+\dotsb+ B_n)$ satisfies the log Sobolev inequality. He then uses the central limit theorem to take the continuous limit and prove the log Sobolev inequality for the Gaussian measure.

I have operators $B'_i$ which satisfy the inequality $$\int f^2 \left(\log \frac{f}{\lVert f\rVert_2}\right)^2 d\mu\leq \langle B_i'f,f\rangle$$ on discrete probability spaces $\{-1,1\}$ with probabilities $\{1/2,1/2\}$. However in order to prove that $B'_1+\dotsb+ B'_n$ also satisfies the same inequality (and then use the central limit theorem to get the continuous limit), I was trying to prove that perhaps $e^{-tB_i'}$ are also hypercontractive perhaps with respect to an Orlicz norm. I would then use a variant of Segal's lemma. However, there are some obstructions to this.

1. The kernel of the operator $e^{-tB'}$ is not positive, which is a necessary condition to use Segal's lemma. Note that $B'$ is not even a Markov generator (don't know if that is important).
2. I have been unable to find any Orlicz norm with respect to which $e^{-tB'}$ is hypercontractive. Perhaps trying to prove hypercontractivity is the wrong path here?

Again, I am trying to prove that if $B_i'$ satisfy the above inequality, then $(B_1'+\dotsb+ B_n')$ also satisfies this inequality.

Comment: TeX notes: for norms, you want `\lVert \rVert`.  Compare, for example, $||f||$ `||f||` to $\lVert f\rVert$ `\lVert f\rVert`.  (`\| \|` is better but can fail, e.g., $\|-f\|$ `\|-f\|` vs. $\lVert-f\rVert$ `\lVert-f\rVert`.) Also, `\dots` can only work their magic with sufficient context; compare, e.g., $B_1' + \dots B_n'$ `B_1' + \dots B_n'` to $B_1' + \dots + B_n'$ `B_1' + \dots + B_n'`.  You can explicitly tell the compiler you want "**dots** for **b**inary operators" using `\dotsb`, as, for example, $B_1' + \dotsb B_n'$ `B_1' + \dotsb B_n'`, if that is what you want.  I edited both of these.

Comment: @LSpice- Thank you, appreciate the edits.